# How to terminate entire Java webapp when Liquibase exception occured at start-up

Tags: servlets, launch

I have a Java EE 7 app with EJB 3 and Servlets running in WebSphere 9. At start-up Liquibase is initializing and running the database scripts.
If Liquibase throws an exception, I would like that the entire Java Webapp is terminated and that it doesn't start.

How can I terminate the entire Java Webapp when Liquibase throws an exception?

Comment: This has been asked and answered before, perhaps by me. Unfortunately, the Servlet spec of old (version 4) neglected to define a way to stop the launch of a web app. The spec defines a hook to trap for the launch but has no mechanism to interrupt that launch. A workaround is to use that hook to post a global value such as an app-level attribute that indicates whether you consider your web app to be in good shape. Your login form for each user can test for this flag, and refuse to permit logins where appropriate. (I do not know if Servlet 6 fills this gap in functionality.)

Comment: "neglected" :/ Wasn't it you who neglected to create an issue at Servlet spec with a request to standardize this and discuss the possible solutions? You as community member can just contribute to the EE specs.